# How can I override Identity Core register.cshtml with a Register.razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I added the Identity Core to my Blazor Server app with the Identity scaffolding. When doing so, I had it write out a copy of Register.cshtml so I could edit it. That worked correctly.

I then created a Register.razor to replace the page with a Blazor page (so I can use the component library we use for all of our pages).

The Register.razor page works fine - if it has a unique url. But if I give it:

```
@page "/Identity/Account/Register"
```

then going to https://localhost:7229/identity/account/register brings up the original Register page in the Identity dll. How can I set it so my razor page is called instead of the MVC page in the Identity dll?

The basic problem is there are two pages with the same url and I need mine to be the one selected when that url is requested.

Note: Yes the "correct" solution is to remove the MVC register.cshtml. Unfortunately that is in the Identity dll and I need that dll.

Comment: Hi @David Thielen, Did you change the order of route matching in `program.cs`? In default, The route will preferentially match razor component with the specified route(`@page "/Identity/Account/Register"`). So i am not sure why route will preferentially match the original Register page in the Identity dll in your project.

Comment: @XinranShen I've left program.cs alone as it was created for a Blazor server app. It's a weird mix because the Identity stuff is MVC while everything else is Blazor. I have a bad feeling that the Identity route somehow gets precedence and it looks for a local MVC RegisterModel : PageModel class. Since a .razor file does not implement PageModel, it won't consider it. ???

Comment: I am not sure why the route work different from default, But i think you can use `@page "/xxx"` to specify a different route for  the original Register page, then `https://localhost:7229/identity/account/register` will only match your custom Register.razor

Comment: @XinranShen That's what I decided to do - have a different route to register and put my Blazor page there. And then have the original one in OnGet() redirect there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works great.

Step 1 - write a distinct .razor page to handle registration. Nothing to do with the existing MVC register.cshtml page. Rather a clean new Blazor page.

In Register.cshtml.cs add the following:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    // go to the Blazor register page
    LocalRedirect("/Account/Register");
}
```

And done. So don't edit/revise the existing MVC page, create a new page at a new page location.